# Asking for a new String with a while loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a game in Java where there are two players. The first player thinks of a word and tells the program how many characters are there in the word they thought and the second player must guess the letters so they can find out what the word was.

But if the second player puts something that's not a letter, the program should ask for another letter, but even if the player puts a letter, it will always ask for a new letter no matter what.

Here's what I've done so far

NOTE: The game is not fully ready yet
FYI: I'm relatively new to programming

```
static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int intentos = 25;
        System.out.println("Número de inentos: " + intentos);
        System.out.print("Número de caracteres: ");
        int length = kbd.nextInt();
        kbd.nextLine();
        
        while(length <= 0){
            System.out.println("Número de caracteres no valido, por favor introduzca otro.");
            System.out.print("Número de caracteres: ");
            length = kbd.nextInt();
        }
        
        String word = WordConEspaciosVacios(length);
        System.out.println("Palabra: "+ word);
        
        do{
            System.out.print("Letra deseada: ");
            String letra = kbd.nextLine();
            
            while(!EsLetra(letra)){ //Problem is here
                System.out.print("Letra deseada: ");
                letra = kbd.nextLine();
                kbd.nextLine();
            }
        } while(HayHuecos(word) && intentos != 0);
    }
    
    private static String WordConEspaciosVacios(int n){
        String word = "";
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            word = word+"_";
        }
        
        return word;
    }
    
    private static boolean HayHuecos(String word){
        boolean HayHuecos = false;
        char First;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length() && !HayHuecos; i++){
            First = word.charAt(i);
            if(First == '_'){HayHuecos = true;}
        }
        
        return HayHuecos;
    }
    
    public static boolean EsLetra(String letra){
        String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        boolean EsLetra = false;
        letra = letra.toLowerCase();
        
        if(letra.length() == 1){
            for(int i = 0; i < abc.length() && !EsLetra; i++){
                if(abc.charAt(i) == letra.charAt(0)){EsLetra = true;}
            }
        }
        
        return EsLetra;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things -

1. Instead of using your `EsLetra` method, you should consider using `Character.isLetter()` to check if a character is a letter.
2. This will also allow you to use `kbd.next()` instead of `kbd.nextLine()` to take in a `char` instead of a `String`.
3. Finally, I think your problem isn't in the inner `while` condition, it's in the do-while loop. As far as I can see, that runs infinitely because neither `intentos` nor `word` change, so there is no terminating condition.